# synonym for "tutor" -- American English

Tags: synonyms

I need to translate "tutor" to a language where the same spelling is a false cognate.  It would help me be creative to look at a few synonyms.  But all I've come up with is "private teacher" which brings more problems, because "private" is hard to express in the target language (Latin American Spanish, if you're curious).

Comment: Mentor? Instructor? Trainer? Educator?

Comment: Note that "private", in this sense, means "not employed by the public schools".  There may be a more meaningful way to express that concept in LA Spanish.

Comment: The Oxford Spanish-English dictionary gives the same translation as the one I came up with, which is also the most highly voted answer to your question on the Spanish Language stack. Although [Taboo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taboo_\(game\))-like explanation hunting is a useful technique for conversation in a foreign language, a dictionary is more useful for writing, which gives you the time to use one.

Comment: Enter "tutor synonyms" on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either mentor, trainer, or educator. But if you want to translate the word don't got too far, tutor in spanish means tutor (same word, almost same pronunciation). I hope it helps you!
And by the way tutor in spanish isn't a false cognate, i speak spanish and i know the meaning of the word. Tutor in spanish means: a person who tutors you and teaches you after school and can  also supervise you.